# How ı can access file in local ip adress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

`<a href = "//192.168.1.41/User/Folder/pdfname.pdf">`

When clicking the button. I want open the file in the local ip adress on the new tab.

Exception : Not allowed to load local resource.

Comment: that IP needs to be a webserver

Comment: What does the HTTP request/response look like in this case?  I don't see any reason why that shouldn't work, provided you're running a web server on `192.168.1.41`.

Comment: If you are using server software such as apache, you will have to put your file in apache's  designated directory

Comment: Maybe [Web server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb) could help you?